# sklearn random forest not parallelizing

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn 0.16 on Ubuntu 12.04 and running:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
X=np.random.rand(5000,500)
y=(np.random.rand(5000).round())
RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=10,n_estimators=1000).fit(X,y)
```

However it's not using up my cores, and takes the same time as n_jobs=1.  Any ideas on how to debug what's going on here?

This screenshot shows some other things running that are busy, but htop has always been showing available CPUs:

[image]

Comment: That should not happen. How many cores do you have? My best bet would be you are on a VM with only one core. What does your htop look like?

Comment: @AndreasMueller I posted a screenshot, there's definitely cores available....

Comment: Try setting `n_jobs = -1`.  Does it now use all of your cores?

Comment: Are you using OpenBLAS?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
import affinity
import multiprocessing
affinity.set_process_affinity_mask(0, 2**multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
```

Comment: what is affinity and (why) does this work? 2006 affinity..?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the `n_jobs` parameter.

Using `n_jobs=-1` will make it use all available cores.